# not able to install GCC on Solaris 11.4

Tags: unix, gcc, terminal, solaris

I installed `Solaris 11.4 x86` in VirtualBox. I need to install the GCC compiler so that I can run c code in Solaris. But each time I try to install the package this error occurs:

```
Errors were encountered while attempting to retrieve package or file data for the
requested operation. Details follow:
http protocol error: Unknown error code: 500 reason: Internal Server Error
URL: 'http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/solaris/file/1/53eb07cd6fade116a6fdea7397c6839929ec0925'
```

publisher information:

[image]

I have used the following commands:

```
   sudo pkg install developer/gcc/gcc-c-7
```

also tried -nv option

```
sudo pkg install -nv gcc
sudo pkg install -nv gcc-7
sudo pkg install -nv developer/gcc-7
```

see the output of the following command:

```
kashif@OS:~$ pkg list | grep GCC
```

output:

```
system/library/gcc/gcc-c++-runtime                7.3.0-11.4.0.0.1.14.0      i--
system/library/gcc/gcc-c++-runtime-7              7.3.0-11.4.0.0.1.14.0      i--
system/library/gcc/gcc-c-runtime                  7.3.0-11.4.0.0.1.14.0      i--
system/library/gcc/gcc-c-runtime-7                7.3.0-11.4.0.0.1.14.0      i--
```

image below shows gcc package information from repostiry

[image]

I am trying to solve this problem for 2 days. I have read documentation from

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E60979/publisher-config.html

I also tried to install developerstudio 12.6 but it didn't work.

overall picture of error and command:

[image: image showing error]

I have googled for errors tried to find information about errors and searched for how to install GCC on Oracle Solaris 11. I couldn't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: *I installed Solaris 11.4 x86 in VirtualBox*  How much RAM and disk space does your VM have.  It needs **at least** 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewHenle for your response. I have given exactly 4GB of RAM to Solaris 11.4. The total RAM installed in my laptop is 8GB. Host OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: How large of a disk drive?  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E60973/glmru.html for space requirements.

Comment: Recommended minimum Disk Space is 13GB. I have given 31GB of Disk Space.

Comment: Try again with a clean install?  The `500` error from the Oracle URL could indicate Oracle was having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "wget [http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/p5i/0/developer%2Fgcc.p5i"](http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/p5i/0/developer%2Fgcc.p5i%22) or your preferred gcc package and manually install it with pkg install. You can try:

pkg install -v

after downloading.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31175603)